# Parsing Javadocs into memory for use within JVM

Tags: java, javadoc

---

## Original Question

> Are there any libraries which exist that allow you to parse a remote
>   HTML version of javadocs?
>   Aside from custom Json/Gson implementations, do any libraries exist for something like
>
> `Map<Class, Entry<Field[],Method[]>> data = Library.get("website.com/docs");`

---

## Original Goal

> Load all available API calls into something I'm working on and use
>   reflection to make those API calls.

---

## Original Problem

> I've done countless searches and can not seem to find anything. Of
>   course I can do it myself, but I'd rather save myself the time if
>   something already exists.

---

### Solution: I've created something to download the javadocs, parse them, and store them into the memory value defined above in the original question section.

**If anyone approaches this question aiming to find the same thing, feel free to comment or message me.**

Comment: Thos sounds soo much like WSDL: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language

Comment: Is not like you want to see the documentation of the library while you are coding correct? you do want to make an application to load the HTML version of the javadocs in memory while the app is running.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code the javadoc was generated from? Parsers for that are easily available, and could write the API docs in a more suitable format.

Comment: Yes @meriton and Yes White_King I am aiming to make function calls by using reflection based off of the given javadocs API. For a custom front-end user interface

Comment: This sounds significantly overcomplicated and also extremely insecure.

Comment: Thats regardless of the fact of what im trying to do.